# Selecteddate not updated in wpf datepicker when datepicker contains plain wpf textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker

I have extended a wpf date picker control and in styles I changed the template for date picker textbox style. I put a textbox in the control template of the datepickertextbox:

```
    <Style x:Key="DatePickerTextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="20" />
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
    <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate>

    <TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox"
    Style="{DynamicResource CalendarTextBoxStyle}"
    TabIndex="0"
    Text="{Binding Path=SelectedDate,
    StringFormat='d',
    ConverterCulture={x:Static glob:CultureInfo.CurrentCulture},
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type     maskedDatePickerLib:MaskedDatePicker}}}"
    TextWrapping="Wrap">

    </TextBox>
    </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I have overridden the default template for date picker control only style for datepicker textbox is changed.

Now, the problem is when I select a date through calender it got displayed in text box through binding. but when I delete the date through backspace and if I try to select the same date again from calender, It does not get displayed in text box. When I investigated through snoop I saw the in SelectedDate property of DatePicker control the value I deleted is still there but in text box text propery value is empty as I deleted it. Kindly suggest.

Comment: I'm guessing this is because the SelectedDate hasn't changed (you just deleted a bit from the textbox, but the underlieing value is still the same). Therefore the SelectedDate property changes is never raised and so the textbox never updates. I'm sure if you selected a different date to the current one the text box would update, am I correct?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, Selecting a different date works.

Comment: Could you post the code for the `SelectedDate` property?

Comment: there is no code in seleceted date property.I just have above style used with default templete and follwoing code:                              /// <summary>
    /// Class implements custom masked date picker. 
    /// </summary>
    public class MaskedDatePicker : DatePicker
    {
        }

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the default `ControlTemplate` for the `DatePicker` control, you will see that it has four inner controls that have names that start with the `PART_` prefix. (You can find the default `ControlTemplate` for the `DatePicker` control in the [DatePicker Syles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468215(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN). Here is an example from the linked page:

```
<Button x:Name="PART_Button"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                Focusable="False"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Margin="3,0,3,0"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Style="{StaticResource DropDownButtonStyle}"
                VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

The controls that have names that start with the `PART_` prefix are internally used by the `DatePicker` class and so not having them in the new `ControlTemplate` will cause problems. The class asks for the controls by name and if they are not found, then default functionality cannot be completed.

Furthermore, you are trying to replace a `DatePickerTextBox` with all of its built in functionality for a normal `TextBox` and then wondering why the default functionality is not working properly... it's because you removed it and didn't replace it.

While I can see that you have tried to use the `PART_` name it is clear that you don't *fully* understand what it does. The `PART_TextBox` control in the default `ControlTemplate` is of type `DatePickerTextBox`, but yours is of type `TextBox`, so whatever the `DatePicker` class normally does with that control, it now cannot do because it is of the wrong type.

Comment: Could you kindly suggest how can i add masking then to WPF date picker.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are referring to by using the word masking... why would you want to mask a `DatePicker`?

Comment: I want user to add the date only in dd/MM/yyyy format. Where user only need enter date part month part and year part manually in text box. Initially a mask is displayed in date picker text box (__.__.____). here user can replace the prompt mask character '_' by entering numeric. he need not to enter date seprator'.'.

Comment: Personally I think that you're creating more work for yourself and more confusion for your users than is required. The `DatePicker` already enables users to enter dates in a wide variety of formats including ones without specifying separator characters. Your users will most likely be used to that freedom.

Comment: It is a requirement from customer that he needs to masking in date picker. Masking is quite handy while adding dates manually. masking can be referred from this online demo :  http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/input/examples/radmaskedtextbox/firstlook/defaultcs.aspx. however it is just to share with what i meant with masking.